# Can I un-check a group of RadioBottoms inside a group box?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, radio-button, groupbox

radio bottoms inside a group Box will be treated as a group of bottoms. They are mutual exclusive. How can I clean up their check states??

I have several radio bottoms, one of them are checked.
How can I "clean" (uncheck) all radio bottoms??
"setChecked" doesn't work within a group, I tried to do following things but failed.

My code is as following, radioButtom is inside a groupBox, and I want to unchecked it.
The first setChecked does works, but the second one doesn't, the radioBottom doesn't been unchecked

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QRadioButton *radioButton;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    radioButton->setChecked(true);
    radioButton->setChecked(false);
}
```

Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to disable the `autoExclusive` property before unchecking it, then re-enabling it.

```
ui->radioButton->setChecked(true);
ui->radioButton->setAutoExclusive(false);
ui->radioButton->setChecked(false);
ui->radioButton->setAutoExclusive(true);
```

After this, the radioButton is unchecked.

Comment: I remember working through this problem once, before SO existed to help me find answers like this.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt documentation said: *A QRadioButton is an option button that can be switched on (checked) or off (unchecked). Radio buttons typically present the user with a "one of many" choice. In a group of radio buttons only one radio button at a time can be checked; if the user selects another button, the previously selected button is switched off.* AFAIK I think that you will not be able to check off all QRadioButtons.

In my practice, I have never seen all checked off at once QRadioButtons in one dialog/window. But may be I have mistaken.

As the solution from my side, I may offer you to create one additional QRadioButton, and then hide it, so, when you need to **hide** all QRadioButton on one widget, you could just setChecked(true) on the hidden one.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still thinking about how to adjust my UI to make it more clear and convenience. This might be a good way ^^